# Product measure; support on a graph

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\pi$ a probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such as 
$$
\pi (A\times \mathbb{R}) =\mu(A) \text{  and  } \pi(\mathbb{R} \times B)=\nu(B)
$$
and 
$$
\forall (x,y),(x',y')\in \Gamma, x<x' \Rightarrow y\le y'
$$
with $\Gamma$ the support of the measure $\pi$.

> Theorem : If $\mu$ is atomless then it exists a map $T : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined $\mu$-a.e. such
>   that $\pi$ is concentrated on the graph of $T$.

Does somebody know how to prove it? It would be a relief for me because I don't see how.

And just to be sure the sentence "$\pi$ is concentrated on the graph of $T$" means $\Gamma = N \cup G(T)$ with $\pi(N)=0$ and $G(T)$ the graph of $T$ ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: With that condition on the support, we can conclude that $T$ is monotone.

Comment: If something is not clear I can clarify it, don't hesitate to talk to me.

Answer (score 0):

I made a progress,  let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\pi$ a probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such as 
$$
\pi (A\times \mathbb{R}) =\mu(A) \text{  and  } \pi(\mathbb{R} \times B)=\nu(B)
$$

Let $\Gamma$ be the support of $\pi$. If
$$
\Gamma \subseteq G_{T}
$$
with $G_{T}$ the graph of the $\mu$ mesurable function $T$ then 
$$
T_{\text{#}} \mu = \nu
$$

A question, for the beauty of mathematics, is the controverse true ?

Anyway, let's go back to our problem, this step is not important to answer to my question. But it's a important application for me, I hope you will understand why I'm really interested in this problem now.

Thank you for your help and regards.

PS : Maybe we can use convex range for atomless measure to solve it !